# Execute Javascript function in the page being loaded by XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

how should I execute a javascript function inside the specified page in XMLHttpRequest? if i have something like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "page1.php?q=" + mydata, true);
```

how should I execute a JS function that would,let's say "alert" mydata's value when I am in page1.php page?

Comment: You might confuse something. Perhaps you mean to execute JavaScript once the HTTP request to 'page1.php?q=...' has been answered. Or do you really want to return JavaScript in the HTTP reply and execute it, similar to JSONP perhaps?

Comment: yes.. once request is answered, the contents of the page should be displayed and a Javascript function should be executed ..is that possible? i am a newbie so.. i have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to put the JavaScript inside the PHP page because that is pointless.  You just want to mine the PHP page for data or send data.  If you want to run a JavaScript after execution of the PHP page, you specify that in the "onreadystatechange" for your xmlhttp object.  Change the readyState and status to suit your tastes

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    // complete and received stuff back
    if( xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200 ){
        // callback function goes here
    }
}
```